# Why are screenshots on some websites are blocked in Windows, but not in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, video, browser, screenshot

While using Windows 10 (Build 19042), I tried taking a screenshot of frame from a video played on a popular website using Google Chrome and Edge browsers, and the video player part of the website was blackened (on purpose, I assume).

This fails when using the <kbd>prt sc</kbd> keyboard button, snipping tool, and <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> utils.

When using Chromium web browser in Ubuntu however, taking screenshots with any available tools does not block the video section.

I assume in Linux systems such censoring is not possible due to the [X Window System architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture), thus such censoring methods are less possible to achieve.

Is this some sort of hard-coded feature in Windows 10 regarding copyrights, or is it a web browser hardcoded feature? If it's Windows that's doing it, how does the OS recognize a video block to be censored inside a running software such as a web browser?

Comment: Hypothesis: [hardware overlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_overlay#Screen_shots).

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented as an API in web browsers. Web applications can use this interface to protect "their" content.

Have a look at [Encrypted Media Extensions (EME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions) and [What is EME?](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme) for more informations.